# Webrtc That works with Obs Studio

Tags: live, peer, obs

Hello It may seem a little complicated or confusing, but there would be a way to make a Webrtc transmission using the Obs te some platform What do that? Can you do that for Peer Js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OBS has officially add WebRTC support. It is available in `master` now and will be released in `v30`.

OBS uses WHIP, so it requires that your server can accept a SDP via a POST. I also created a reference server for this called [Broadcast Box](https://github.com/glimesh/broadcast-box)

I have left my old answer below. This was from before OBS supported WebRTC.

---

The easiest way to do this would be [project-lightspeed](https://github.com/GRVYDEV/Project-Lightspeed). This uses FTL and then bridges it with WebRTC. This is available in the official OBS build.

FTL uses the same underlying protocol as WebRTC (RTP) so it is very easy to bridge. Broadcasting will be sub-second.

Comment: The release candidate for OBS 30.0 with WHIP support is available for download. Can be used with services such as Twitch, Dolby.io, and more: https://dev.to/dolbyio/top-reasons-for-updating-to-the-new-obs-300-release-g6m